# converting integer to date and getting records based on this date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table (SQLServer 2008r2) with an integer which is a date.  The format is YYYYMMDD (no i did not have design control over this and would not ever do it by choice.  It can not be changed).

I want to convert it into a date and get all the records where this field's value is < the current day minus 14 days.  This is what I have which is working:

```
SELECT * from webFormsInstances where formStage <> 'Complete' 
AND cast(convert(DATETIME, LEFT(formActionDate, 8)) as date) < dateAdd(day,-14,getdate())
order by formActionDateTime desc
```

Is there a better more efficient way to do this way to do this?

Comment: You can use `CONVERT(DATETIME,formActionDate,114)` for date conversion. From `yyyyMMdd` OR you can avoid the column conversion all together and just convert your added 14 to the `yyyyMMdd` format .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a formula on the column, sqlserver will not be able to utilize any index on the column since it must perform the calculation on all rows. 
(look for sargable. e.g. [here](http://richardlees.blogspot.se/2013/08/sargable-predicates-are-usually-best.html))

Do the calculation on the constant instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM webFormsInstances 
WHERE formStage <> 'Complete' 
      AND formActionDate < CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar(8), dateAdd(day,-14, getdate()), 112))
ORDER BY formActionDateTime DESC
```

Comment: yes this is nice.  My method was converting the formActionDate into a date for every record.   Since there are a high number and growing your suggestion look much better for a few reasons.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one.

```
declare @t table(id int, formStage varchar(50),  formActionDate int)

insert into @t values (1 ,'notComplete', 20150101), (2 ,'Complete', 20150128),(3 ,'notComplete', 20150129),(2 ,'notComplete', 20150131),(3 ,'notComplete', 20150201),(4 ,'notComplete', 20150209),(5 ,'notComplete' , 20150220), 
(6 ,'notComplete', 20150115),(7,'notComplete', 20150113)

select CONVERT(DATETIME, cast(formActionDate as varchar) ,114),* from @t 
where formStage <> 'complete'

SELECT * from @t where formStage <> 'Complete' 
AND --cast(convert(DATETIME, LEFT(formActionDate, 8)) as date) 
CONVERT(DATETIME, cast(formActionDate as varchar) ,114)
< dateAdd(day,-14,getdate())
order by formActionDate desc
```